# How to append timecode into metadata using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, centos7

We have a request to append output/timecode into metadata starting from frame 0.
It is done in nuke with addtimecode node, starting at frame 0 and timecode as 00:00:00:00 with a prefix of "output"

I'm trying to do it with ffmpeg but nto able to get it :(
I have tried with `-metadata output/timecode="00:00:00:00"` It didn't work

Answer (score 0):

[Metadata fields](https://learn.foundry.com/nuke/content/comp_environment/metadata/rendering_metadata.html) are dependent on your output format.